# Publish maven artifact with custom separator

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

For deploying to tomcat with versions, I want to have artifact generated with command `mvn package` like artifact-name##1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war .

I am able to achieve this using the following

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}##${project.version}</finalName>
</build
```

But while publishing to nexus, still artifact is being published without taking this change.  artifact-name-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war is being published to nexus. I think this is expected with maven. Can I override this behavior to publish something like artifact-name##1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war ?

Comment: The finalName will only change the name for the `target` directory. You can not change the format for the maven repositories. It's fixed. As already answered by J Fabian Meier

Answer (score 2):

No.

The file format for Maven repositories (like Nexus/Artifactory, but also the local repository) is fixed.